# cocos2d-x on exit callback?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I need to run some cleanup and tear-down code before the application exits.

I have already written my onExit function which I will call before calling Director::end. But I need this callback to run when the user quits the application by closing the window.

As far as I can tell, neither cocos2d::Application nor cocos2d::ApplicationProtocol define an any kind of on exit or on quit virtual method which can be overridden.

Comment: You can put the cleanup into the destructor of the class that holds your state. As long as it is destructed, your code will be executed. Alternatives are using `std::atexit`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` in *AppController.mm* if it's not already implemented in your cocos project (in my *cocos2d_tests.xcodeproj* it already is), and from there call your `onExit` function.

Something like:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // call onExit() here, or forward the call to call onExit() :)
}
```

**Note**: this is only valid for iOS. For Android, there's not equivalent to `applicationWillTerminate` as far as I know.

Comment: I see that it's defined in AppController.mm. I'm not really familiar with gluing Objective-C and C++ together. I'm guessing it uses reflection to see if your Application class has the applicationWillTerminate method; it's not defined in any of the C++.

Comment: you can call any function from Application, like so: `Application::GetInstance()->foo()` after you've implemented `foo()` in `Application`. You can call C++ code in .mm files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but i want to answer it anyway.

I have created a GameController class and AppDelegate has a a pointer to this class.
This GameController class is going to handle at least the first scene or the scenes changing along the game.
For example, this is my AppDelegate.h:

```
#ifndef  _APP_DELEGATE_H_
#define  _APP_DELEGATE_H_

#include "cocos2d.h"

class GameController;
/**
@brief    The cocos2d Application.

Private inheritance here hides part of interface from Director.
*/
class  AppDelegate : private cocos2d::Application
{
public:
    AppDelegate();
    virtual ~AppDelegate();

    virtual void initGLContextAttrs() override;

    /**
    @brief    Implement Director and cocos2d::Scene* init code here.
    @return true    Initialize success, app continue.
    @return false   Initialize failed, app terminate.
    */
    virtual bool applicationDidFinishLaunching() override;

    /**
    @brief  Called when the application moves to the background
    @param  the pointer of the application
    */
    virtual void applicationDidEnterBackground() override;

    /**
    @brief  Called when the application reenters the foreground
    @param  the pointer of the application
    */
    virtual void applicationWillEnterForeground() override;

private:
    GameController* m_gameController;
};

#endif // _APP_DELEGATE_H_
```

The Class GameController has a public function Destroy instance where i do the cleanup of all other scenes, classes, etc.
So in the Destructor of the AppDelegate i call that function:

AppDelegate.cpp:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"

#include "GameController.h"
#include "extensions/cocos-ext.h"

USING_NS_CC;

AppDelegate::AppDelegate() : m_gameController(nullptr)
{
}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate()
{
    m_gameController->DestroyInstance();
}

...
...
...
```

After initializing everything in AppDelegate.cpp and before returning true i call GameController::GetInstance() static function

```
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
...
...
...

m_gameController = GameController::GetInstance();

if (!m_gameController)
    {
        log("\n[AppDelegate] [Fatal] - GameController is nullptr.\n");
        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

Then the GameController will (as the name suggest) control the game, and in the game end (or the window geting closed on Win32, Mac osx, or linux) you can do the clean up in the GameController::DestroyInstance() called by AppDelegate Destructor.

This is part of my Gamecontroller.h:

```
#ifndef _GAME_CONTROLLER_H_
#define _GAME_CONTROLLER_H_

#include <atomic>

class GameController
{
public:
    ~GameController();

    static GameController* GetInstance();
    void DestroyInstance();
...
...
...
```

And this is part of my GameController.cpp:

```
#include "GameController.h"

static GameController* s_gameController = nullptr;

GameController::GameController()
{

}

GameController::~GameController()
{

}

GameController * GameController::GetInstance()
{
    if (!s_gameController)
    {
        s_gameController = new (std::nothrow) GameController;
        if (s_gameController)
        {
            if (!s_gameController->Init())
            {
                delete s_gameController;
                s_gameController = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
    return s_gameController;
}

void GameController::DestroyInstance()
{
    if (s_gameController)
    {
        delete s_gameController;
        s_gameController = nullptr;
    }
}
...
...
...
```

Hope it helps:D